# MongoDB Replica Set Healtcheck - HostUnreachable

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, database

I've been having trouble setting up my Mongo v3.2 replica set / cluster. I've included `mongod`s logs with inline comments from A) the node I initialized the replica set from and B) another node (rest of peers are having same issue). In short, the issue is that the heartbeat from all the other nodes to the node I initially setup the replica set from keep failing due to HostUnreachable, but I'm not sure how to debug further, as `mongo <initial node>` works fine from all the other nodes so I don't think it's a network access problem. After some Googling, I assumed this was due to the bindIp setting I had in my Mongo config file (or the lack thereof), but listing all node IPs there doesn't seem to do the trick.

See the mongodb config files & logs here-

https://gist.github.com/tejasmanohar/f0e705fb0d9e96f68e05e1ab20c478be

Why could this healthcheck be failing and/or how I can debug further or maybe reproduce the failed connection apart outside of `mongod` (I can `ping` and connect via `mongo` to all peers from each host)? Thanks!

**Update:**

`options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: true }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" } }`

I noticed that the `mongod` logs show `bindIp: true` rather than a list set in my Mongo configuration file. Is that problematic? I tried providing a comma-separated string instead of an array since the type of the field is a bit [unclear in docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) but same result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are setting the ips of the other machines on bindIp, but you should use the machine's ip that is reachable by the others.

For example, on your `mongo-initial.q` machine, your bindIp should be like:

```
"bindIp": "127.0.0.1,10.0.11.2"
```

More info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#architecture).

Don't know if it will fix everything but it's a start.

Comment: Ah, that's right... but still no luck :(. I see `"Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup; NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset"` at startup on all the nodes. Is that problematic? The bindIp option is also logged as `true` in `mongod` logs rather than an array (see gist from original post). I feel as though I'm misconfiguring something there but can't nail what.

Comment: That was it... had to be a comma-separated string, not list.

Comment: Wow I didn't see that. I'll update my answer to reflect it

Comment: I still don't understand why it's a bool in the mongod output haha

Comment: can't imagine how they are using these values XD
anyway, updated the answer with the right value

Comment: haha me neither TBH. oops, I have "answered my own question" in SO already but btw you need to encompass the IPs in your updated answer with "". this isn't YAML haha (well, it is I guess since JSON is a subset)

Comment: I see, I've mixed the things :( NOW it should be correct

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution doesn't make 100% sense to me yet, but I had to change `bindIps` setting to a comma-separated string instead of an array. Array seems to work in YAML but not JSON. Still don't understand why it logged out as a bool before. @andresk pointed out something else wrong about my solution-- my `bindIp` setting had my peer IPs but not the own host.